# AVSpeechSynthesizer freezes iOS app for a few seconds

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer

Using AVSpeechSynthesizer in my ARKit app makes the app freeze for a few seconds before a sound is emitted. I've created this helper class:

```
public class TextToSpeech {
    class func speak(text: String) {
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "EN")
        utterance.rate = 0.3
        let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    }
}
```

However, when I call its class function, the app freezes for a few seconds.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    ...

    @objc func didTapButton() {
        TextToSpeech.speak(text: "test") // it works but it freezes the app temporarily
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter where in the code I call this. I've tried to enclose this call in a `DispatchQueue` but it still doesn't work. How can I fix this freeze? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Hey. Looks like it's connected with the internal `AVSpeechSynthesizer ` queue. You can try to make it manage the thing in background, since there's no mention about `AVSpeechSynthesizer` is main thread only. Do so by adding the last line (`synthesizer.speak(utterance)`) call to the background queue: like that: `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { synthesizer.speak(utterance) }`

Comment: I think the reason why you have ui blocked is because *synthesizer instance is created in the function scope* so it's lifespan is too short, and it has to block current thread to speak. So you must wait till synthesizer finish speaking before being deallocated on the exit from your `speak()` method.

Comment: Hey @OlegShanyuk that works great. Please go ahead and post that as an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's connected with the internal `AVSpeechSynthesizer` queue. You can try to make it manage the thing in background, since there's no mention about `AVSpeechSynthesizer` is main thread only. 
Do so by adding the last line (`synthesizer.speak(utterance)`) call to the background queue capturing references to the `synthesizer` and `utterance` objects like that:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { 
    synthesizer.speak(utterance) 
}
```

I think the reason why you have ui blocked is because `synthesizer` instance has to block current thread to speak. So you must wait till synthesizer finish speaking before being deallocated on the exit from your `speak()` method.

Comment: .default may be a more appropriate qos. From docs: "Assign this class to tasks or queues that your app initiates or uses to perform active work on the user's behalf."